# How to Angular 7 Material design using responsive layout?

Tags: angular, material-design

I am using a angular 7 material design but column spread in desktop but responsive no idea. Any body explain for responsive layout

Comment: Add some of your codes, then others could help

Answer (score 2):

For using layouting in Angular in combination with material you should use the official angular flexlayout --> https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

To be honest I prefer using the bootstrap utility classes, especially the grid system is quite good. To integrate with Material and Bootstrap you would only need to include/import the css u want to use (in your styles.scss), like the grid system, text classes, color classes etc. --> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities

Here you will find the utility classes.

Kind regards